# How to fetch and display blob images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I am trying to save images to indexeddb and then fetch and display them in a react app.
My approach is to convert images to a blob and save the blob url to indexeddb and then when it's time to display, fetch the blob url and set the image url as .src.

How I created the blob

```js
fetch(imgurl, {
                mode: 'no-cors',
                method: "get",
                headers: {
                     "Content-Type": "application/json"
                } 
             }) 
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(async images => {
               
                    var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(images)
                  
                    var blobA = blob_url.replace("blob:","") 
                    var blobB = blobA.replace('"','')
```

this is bloburl
blob:http://localhost:3000/d7a55f39-b496-476b-8c3c-857874bd107c

I then remove blob: and save this url in indexeddb to be fetched when needed
http://localhost:3000/d7a55f39-b496-476b-8c3c-857874bd107c

this is where I need to use the blob image

```js
import React from "react";
import { Row, Col, Container, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

   
function Item({ item }) { 
    const imgurl = item.productimg
    fetch(imgurl)
        .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
        .then(async blob => {
            const test = await blobToImage(blob)  
            console.log("image test",test)
        
            let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           let myImage = document.getElementById('myImg')
           myImage.src = objectURL;
            
        });
       
    return (
        <div className="item" id={item.id}>


            <Row>
                <Col> 
                <Image  id="myImg" width="50" height="58" rounded />

                </Col>
                <Col xs={6}>
                    <div className="item-info">
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                    </div>
                </Col>
                <Col>3 of 3</Col>
            </Row>
           

            <div className="item-actions">
                <button className="btn-remove">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Item;
```

Item contains all the productdata including the saved blob url. The problem is the images are not showing and I could not figure out why.

what could i be doing wrong and how can I display the images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Don't modify the `Blob`'s URL.

When you took the `blob:` part out of the URL string to the `Blob`, the browser no longer knew that you were referencing your `Blob`. Instead, try leaving the URL alone after creating it with [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static).

On top of that, when synchronizing a component with an external resource (like fetching data), you should use [React's `useEffect` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

### Example with React

You can [view this example live at StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-66600991-cdy9zf?file=src%2FApp.js).

```js
function Item({ item }) {
  const imgURL = item.productimg;
  const [blobURL, setBlobURL] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController(); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController
    const signal = controller.signal;
    fetch(imgURL, { signal })
      .then((res) => res.blob()) // Get the response and return it as a blob
      .then((blob) => { // Create a URL to the blob and use it without modifying it.
        setBlobURL(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      })
      .catch((error) => { // Error handling here
        console.error(error);
      });

    // Cancel the fetch request on any dependency change
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, [imgURL]);

  return (
    <div className="item" id={item.id}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          {blobURL ? <Image src={blobURL} id="myImg" width="50" height="58" rounded /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
        </Col>
        <Col xs={6}>
          <div className="item-info">
            <p>{item.name}</p>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col>3 of 3</Col>
      </Row>

      <div className="item-actions">
        <button className="btn-remove">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Example with plain JavaScript

```js
const imgURL = "https://cdn62.picsart.com/182788826000202.jpg?type=webp&to=crop&r=256"
fetch(imgURL)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    document.getElementById('my-img').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  })
```

```html
<img id="my-img" />
```

Good Luck...

Comment: I have this error when I use this.Cannot set property 'src' of undefined ...why?

Comment: The `useEffect` in this solution needs work. It doesn't list `igmurl` as its dependency, and if it did, you would also need to add an AbortController to stop `imageRef` being modified when `imgurl` changes rapidly.

Comment: Hi @Andria, thanks for that!! I had no idea that `AbortControllers` existed!!  I've also updated the deps for `useEffect`.  A bonus is that I added the missing `useMemo`...Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 3):

[The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). ObjectURL is not meant to be saved somewhere. You can convert your image to [base64 and store as data-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) instead.