# How to open the photo I get from the API on the card

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, blob

I take a picture of API like this:

```
 const downloadDepositMoneyInfosClickHandler = (row) => {
    service.getDepositMoneyPictureById(row.id, (status, data) => {
      var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/png" });
      var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var download = document.createElement("a");
      download.href = objectUrl;
      download.download = "filename.png";
      download.click();
    });
  };
```

In this case, the photo opens on a new page in the browser..How can I display it on a Card (material ui)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch and display blob images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600991/how-to-fetch-and-display-blob-images)

Comment: I have this error when I use it.Cannot set property 'src' of undefined